# When I install latest .NET Core SDK (2.1.301) app won't run in azure app service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've installed latest .NET Core SDK (2.1.301), create new .NET Core project, published it to azure using Visual Studio and I'm getting:

## HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

I'm using the default package reference without version explicitly stated:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

The official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1) says:

> We recommend relying on the implicit version specified by the SDK and not explicitly setting the version number on the package reference.
>
> When the version is not specified, an implicit version is specified by the SDK, that is, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

So how is that? Why the recommended and default setup does not work?

Answer (score 2):

This is because SDK version 2.1.301 actually targets .NET Core 2.1.1, which has just been released. It always takes a little while before updates are deployed on Azure App Service.

When deployment is complete it will be announced on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues

If you can't wait until it's deployed, you can use a self-contained deployment. This bundles the .NET Core version with your app.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd

Another workaround is to target .NET Core 2.1.0 (SDK version 2.1.300).

Comment: Yeah, what sucks is that without changing anything in source code, just by installing patched version of SDK, it breaks the app in azure. How can I target 2.1.0?

Comment: The easiest way is to set the old SDK version (2.1.300) in global.json. If it doesn't exist, you can create it in the same folder where the sln file lives. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json

Comment: Looks like 2.1.1 has been rolled out. No announcement yet though.